# How to list all users in MediaWiki?

Tags: php, function, variables, mediawiki

I write a MediaWiki extension. I need to get a list of all registered users. In most MediaWiki does not really understand what is and find where the legs grow.

For current logged user i use code:

```
global $wgUser;
$userId = $wgUser->getId();
$userName = $wgUser->getName();
```

But I can not yet find how to get a list of all users and their IDs for future use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to [query](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_access) the [user table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_table) in the databas. Something like this (have a look in the manual linked below for details):

```
$dbr = wfGetDB( DB_SLAVE );
$id_list = $dbr->select( 'user', 'user_id' );
foreach( $id_list as $user_data ) {
    ...
}
```

**Further reading:**

- [Manual:Database access](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_access)
- [Manual:User table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_table)